# How do I add additional file to class path which is not java or scala file using SBT configuration?

Tags: scala, sbt

How do I add additional file to classpath which is not java or scala file using SBT configuration ?

My source folder is defined like this

```
javaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src"
```

I have `jawr.properties` in the root of my `/src` folder. I'd like this file to be copied to `WEB-INF/classes` of my packaged app. I tried changing filter to

```
includeFilter in (Compile, unmanagedSources) := "*.java" || "*.scala" || "jawr.properties",
```

But it fails on `sbt compile` because it tries to compile it as java file.

I'm on SBT 0.13.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want it be an unmanaged resource (not source)

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile := Seq(baseDirectory.value / "src")
includeFilter in unmanagedResources := "jawr.properties"
```

Comment: But the file is in source directory. Otherwise it would have been copied already because default filter for `unmanagedResources` is `*.*` minus `HiddenFiles`. Any other thoughts ?

Comment: I just realized that in order for your original advice to work I need to change default unmanagedResources folder like this `unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile := Seq(baseDirectory.value / "src")`. If you update your answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: Updated. Sorry I missed that line.  In the project where I've had to do this before I thought that was there already, but I must have put it in.

Answer (score 5):

The philosophy of SBT is to work by convention (and not by configuration) as much as possible. So the most straightforward solution, in many cases, isn't to look for the correct setting to tell SBT where your files are... But rather to figure out where SBT already expects to find them. You can check [this page](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Directories.html) of the "getting started with SBT" guide for the basics.

For resource files that needs to be packaged together with compiled classes, the default directory is `src/main/resources` (a convention borrowed from Maven, like most of SBT's default directory structure). Similarly, files in `src/test/resources` are added to the classpath but only during tests.

If, for some reason, you want to use non-standard directories, you will want to have a look at [this page](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html) of the documentation. For resources, the key to modify is `resourceDirectory`:

```
// resources in `resources` instead of `src/main/resources` :
resourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "resources"

// test resources in `test-resources` instead of `src/test/resources` :
resourceDirectory in Test := baseDirectory.value / "test-resources"
```

Comment: I agree with that but I'm the only person on the team who uses SBT, the rest uses ancient ANT script therefore I cannot move files around :)